# Check if index is not 0 in meteor template

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

I know that `{{@index}}` inside an `{{#each}}` in meteor will give the index.
How can i check if index is different from zero.
Exp:

```
{{#each array}}
    {{#if @index != 0}}
    ,
    {{/if}}
   <!-- other code here -->
{{/each}}
```

I want to add comma between words.
Is there a way without using helpers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
{{#each array}}
  {{#unless @index}}
    ...
  {{/unless}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just found out a way without using a helper.
{{#if @index $not 0}}, {{/if}}

Comment: You're correct - the helper isn't necessary. I updated the answer with `unless`, which should be the most compact way to write it.